# Schwa in Webster dictionary

Tags: pronunciation, speech, weak-vowel-merger

Why there are too many sounds marked by **schwa** in Webster's dictionary and how to recognize the correct pronunciation? E.g.:
Cup [*/kʌp/* in Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cup_1?q=cup) and [*\ˈkəp\* in Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cup) 
Notice [*/ˈnəʊtɪs/* in Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/notice_1) and [*\ˈnō-təs\* in Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notice)

and there are even more examples currently I don't remember!

Comment: These often reflect the difference between English (/kʌp/) and American (/kəp/) but also reflect the differences between different accents, differences of opinion, and different methods of transcription (note that Webster's doesn't use IPA). Your best bet is to consult multiple dictionaries, and ensure the ones you consult have pronunciations for the version of English you wish to speak.

Comment: I hear the schwa as more of a grunt than a vowel, a throwaway, passing sound. For being so colorless, it is not as fixed as other vowels. So a schwa here and one there don't have to match.

Comment: Most of the online dictionaries have a 'sound' option next to the written pronunciation. Vowels and their written counterparts are weird - the actual sound is the best thing to follow. (which is to say if I (GenAmE) try to say \ˈnō-təs\ it doesn't feel natural. I think MW's use of schwa is as you say an overuse.

Comment: I think that MW schwa is ridiculous. Sure, speakers of both BrE *and* AmE might reduce the vowel in ***but*** to a schwa in many contexts. But ***cup*** is almost always more fully articulated. And when I click on MW's "sound" option for ***cup***, I can't imagine how anyone could justify calling that a schwa.

Comment: Why would M-W transcribe weak vowels in a way that reflects a merger that not all Americans use? That fails to convey necessary information about American accents that don't have that merger. If instead it had used different symbols for phonemes that some speakers pronounce differently, then speakers with the merger could at least understand the transcriptions even though different symbols mean the same thing for those speakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Is [shut](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shut) closer to a schwa?

Comment: @RosieF: While I pretty much agree with you for the weak vowel merger, there's a limit to how many different accents you can reflect in one dictionary. What would you think of a dictionary that used a different vowel for *pan* and *bat*, like [New Yorkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_accent) do?

Comment: @PeterShor: Not to me, no. And although it's easy for me to think of contexts where unstressed ***but*** uses a schwa (as in most people's enunciation of ***Naughty but nice***), I can't really think of any context where ***shut*** could be so unstressed as to be just a neutral vowel.

Comment: ...in fact, it seems to me most if not all instances of the /ʌ/ vowel that can be reduced are probably very common "function" words. Another that comes to mind is ***some***, which is easily reduced to a schwa in many contexts, but offhand I can't think of any actual verbs or nouns that can do this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: On the other hand, you have John Lawler, who has often claimed on this site that /ʌ/ and /ə/ are identical in American English except for stress.  (They're not in my speech, but we Americans don't all speak alike.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many dialects of American English, /ʌ/ (as in *cup*) and /ə/ (as in the second vowel of *carrot*) are exactly the same vowel sound; they are only distinguished by the fact that /ʌ/ occurs in stressed syllables and is therefore longer. Merriam-Webster has adjusted its pronunciation symbols to reflect these dialects. Not all Americans speak like this (I don't) but it's widespread enough to count as General American pronunciation.

There is also something called the [weak vowel merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_close_front_vowels#Weak_vowel_merger), which occurs in some dialects of both British and American English. In this merger, an /ɪ/ in an unstressed syllable is pronounced like a schwa. Merriam-Webster writes down its pronunciations using the weak vowel merger; Oxford doesn't. This explains Merriam-Webster's schwa in *notice*.

You ask how to recognize the "correct" pronunciation. All of Merriam-Webster's pronunciations are correct in widely used prestigious dialects of American English. If you're trying to speak British English, you're using the wrong dictionary — Oxford is much better for that.

Comment: No I don't want to speak British English, but sometimes like in **cup** the sound I hear is more like a short *ä* sound!

Comment: @Masked Man: That's another valid pronunciation which is found in American English, and which is quite typical of British English. Both pronouncing it this way and pronouncing it like a schwa are "correct".

Comment: I think you got me wrong. Although it's using schwa for denoting the pronunciation when I play the audio it's quite like the sound I mentioned.

Comment: Merriam-Webster's dictionary doesn't make sure that its audio pronunciations match its phonetic notation. For example, for [*Paris*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Paris), Merriam-Webster uses a schwa to denote the pronunciation, but its audio pronunciation is /ˈpɛrɪs/.

Comment: I don't hear it as an R-colored vowel but rather as symbolized, probably because I'm not native 

Comment: @Maked Man: I was talking about the second vowel in *Paris*, actually, not the first.

Comment: Oh, I got that. Thanks for your clarifications anyway!

Comment: It isn't to reflect certain dialects, it's to use the fewest symbols possible. The MW notation is phonemic. Specific qualities of phonetic realizations have no bearing on whether a given phonemic analysis applies to that accent—it is the number and distribution of phonemes that do. And since /ə/ in the traditional analysis only occurs in unstressed syllables, any strong vowel can be analyzed to be the stressed variant of /ə/.

Comment: STRUT is of course the best candidate in the many accents where it is phonetically closer to /ə/ than any other, but their realizations don't need to precisely overlap in order to be considered to belong to the same phoneme.

Comment: @Nardog: but if you don't distinguish between STRUT and schwa, then you end up using the same phonetic notation for the endings of *seagull* and *eagle* (ˈ(s)ē-ˌgəl, in their notation), which isn't quite right if /ə/ and /ʌ/ aren't the same vowel. So MW is using fewer than the absolute minimum number of phonemes.

Comment: You can just write \ˈē-gəl\. In fact that's exactly [what they do](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eagle).